# Evaluate $\int\int | y - x ^2|$ over region [-1,1;0,2]

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider

$$\int\int | y - x ^2|\, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

over the region $[-1,1;0,2]$. I drew the diagram and split the integral as follows/

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\,\mathrm{d}x\int_{x^2}^{2}  y - x ^2\, \mathrm{d}y + 2\int_{0}^{1}\, \mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x^2} -(y - x ^2) \,\mathrm{d}y$$

Is this correct ?

Comment: you might wanna to expand upon the notation you've used. Specifically, please explain what you mean by $[ -1, 1; 0, 2]$.

Comment: I think its rectangle which x coordinates ranging from -1 to 1 and so on

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: @J. Deff have you had a chance to have a look at my answer yet? If so, do you agree with my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your region is given by
$$R = \{ \ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \ -1 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 2 \ \}.$$

Now we note that
$$
\begin{align}
\int\int_{R} \left\lvert y - x^2 \right\rvert &= \int_0^2 \int_{-1}^1 \left\lvert y - x^2 \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_{-1}^1 \left\lvert y - x^2 \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y  + \int_1^2 \int_{-1}^1 \left\lvert y - x^2 \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_{-1}^1 \left\lvert y - x^2 \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y  + \int_1^2 \int_{-1}^1 \left( y - x^2 \right) \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y \\
&= \qquad  \int_0^1 \left( \int_{-1}^0 \left\lvert y - x^2 \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^1 \left\lvert y - x^2 \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} x   \right) \ \mathrm{d} y  \quad + \int_1^2 \int_{-1}^1 \left( y - x^2 \right) \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\left\lvert y - t \right\rvert \ \mathrm{d} t \ \mathrm{d} y  +  \int_1^2 \left( yx - \frac{x^3}{3}  \right)_{x=-1}^{x=1} \ \mathrm{d} y  \qquad \mbox{ [ substitute $x^2 = t$ into both parts of the first $y$-integral ] }\\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} (y-t) \ \mathrm{d} t + \int_y^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} (t-y) \ \mathrm{d} t \right) \ \mathrm{d} y + \int_1^2  \left( 2y - \frac{2}{3} \right) \ \mathrm{d} y \\
&= \int_0^1 \left(  \left( 2y \sqrt{t} - \frac{2t^{3/2}}{3} \right)_{t=0}^{t=y} +  \left( \frac{2t^{3/2}}{3} - 2y \sqrt{t}  \right)_{t=y}^{t=1} \right) + \left( y^2 - \frac{2y}{3} \right)_{y=1}^{y=2} \\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \frac{8y^{3/2}}{3} - 2y + \frac{2}{3} \right) \ \mathrm{d} y + \frac{7}{3} \\
&= \left( \frac{16y^{5/2}}{15} - \frac{2y^3}{3} + \frac{2y}{3}  \right)_{y=0}^{y=1} + \frac{7}{3} \\
&= \frac{16}{15} + \frac{7}{3} \\
&= \frac{51}{15}.
\end{align}
$$

Hope this calculation is correct and clear enough for you.

Comment: I don't seem to get yout method. How have you split these and removed absolute value signs ?

Comment: and I am getting 46/15 ans

Comment: @J.Deff please note that whenever $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, we have $0\leq x^2\leq 1$. That's why I've split the outer $y$-integral into two integrals, in one of which $x^2$ cannot exceed $y$. Hope you can follow my logic now.

Comment: I see. but why have you furthure split integral from y from 0 to 1, based on positive x and negative x side

Comment: @J.Deff that I did to ensure that $x$ stays either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing within either of the two integrals. Actually, we could have just used the result on even functions and simply doubled the innter $x$-integral as $2\int_0^1 \ldots \ \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @J.Deff if $f$ is an even integrable function on the interval $[-a, a]$, then we have $$\int_{-a}^a f = 2 \int_0^a f.$$ Hope you can now appreciate my calculation.

Comment: so my method is not correct ?

Comment: @J.Deff I don't think so. Please have an in-depth look at my calculation and see how you like it.

Comment: why ? whats the problem ?