# Find volume bounded by two cylinders using triple integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Given $x^2+y^2=2ay$ and $z^2=2ay$. I tried to use cylindrical  corordinated but unable to solve the integral

Comment: By "between two cylinders" do you mean "in the intersection of two cylinders"? The question does not seem to make sense otherwise. Could you show more of your work?

Comment: The second equation doesn't correspond to a cylinder

Comment: @RoryDaulton enclosed within the two

Comment: @Coolwater: I believe the problem uses the generalized definition of a cylinder, which uses any planar curve as the base. See [the first definition here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cylinder), though in the problem the base (a parabola) is not closed. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder#Cylindrical_surfaces) explicitly shows a parabolic cylinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $a>0$. Then $x^2+y^2=2ay\iff x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$ and therefore $y\in[0,2a]$. In particular, $y\geqslant0$.

In cylindrical coordinates, you have $r^2=z^2=2ar\sin\theta$. Besides $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, since $y\geqslant0$. So, one needs to compute the triple integral$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{2ar\sin\theta}}^{\sqrt{2ar\sin\theta}}r\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$It turns out that\begin{align}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{2ar\sin\theta}}^{\sqrt{2ar\sin\theta}}r\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}2\sqrt2r^{\frac32}\sqrt{a\sin\theta}\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^\pi\frac{32}5a^3\sin^3\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\frac{128}{15}a^3.\end{align}

Comment: shouldnot z limits go from 0 to your upper limit as there is no part below XY plane of enclosed volume

Comment: Why is that? Doesn't the point $(0,2a,-2a)$ belong to your region?

Comment: does the cylinder $z^2 = 2ay$ have part below xy plane

Comment: That is **not** a cylinder, and it is clear that $(0,2a-2a)$ belongs to that region.

Comment: i solve integral but i got stuck at computing $$\int_{0}^{\pi} (sinx)^{5/2}$$

Comment: can you elaborate how to solve theta integral

Comment: I've done that. What do you think?

Comment: thanks. i missed sin while solving it so it got 5/2

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255958/evaluate-int-int-y-x-2-over-region-1-10-2

Comment: Why does $\theta\in[0,\pi]$.I am not able to get it....

Comment: Because $r\sin\theta=y\geqslant0$.

Comment: Final doubt.I think the z limit is from 2arsin$\theta$ to -2arsin$\theta$ because those are the maximum limits of z but how did you get limits of r...Say i take a random point in the volume region then isn't it going to be less than $$\sqrt{2ar\sin\theta}$$.Say (0,a,a)

Comment: In cyclindrical coordinates, $r$ is the distance from the point to the $z$-axis. So, in this case, $r$ can take values from $0$ to $2a\sin\theta$, since $r^2=x^2+y^2\leqslant2ay=2ar\sin\theta$. Finally, for each $\theta$ and each $r$, $z$ can take values from $-\sqrt{2ar\sin\theta}$ to $\sqrt{2ar\sin\theta}$, since $z^2\leqslant2ar\sin\theta$.