# Difficulty in computing double integral over rectangle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to compute double integral over rectangle with vertices as (0,0), (1,0),(0,1),(1,1)

Given f = {$x + y   ,     x^2 < y <2x^2$

```
        0 , otherwise}
```

I made picture and came up with

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt {y/2}}^{\sqrt{y}} (x+ y )dxdy$.

Not quite sure till here

Comment: It seems ok to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the rectangle, the parabola $y=x^2$ passes through the corner (1,1). The other parabola remains above it. You are first integrating in X and then Y. This is correct. In the other case you would have to split it into two integrals. Can you try in the other form, with order if integration interchanged?

Comment: I know the other form

Comment: That's great. Looks like everything is OK

Comment: i posted similar question earlier today. can you check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255958/evaluate-int-int-y-x-2-over-region-1-10-2